# Rails not picking up custom date & time formats in en.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, formatting, date-format

I'm not that familiar with I18N in Rails so bear with me. Trying to set a custom date & time format:

```
#config/locales/en.yml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      long_dateweek: "%A, %B %d, %Y"
  time:
    formats:
      very_short: "%H:%M"
```

But when I try to use them I just get the default formats:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > Time.now.to_date.to_s(:long_dateweek)
 => "2012-08-22" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > Time.now.to_time.to_s(:very_short)
 => "2012-08-22 16:12:47 -0700"
```

Tried restarting console (and even the server) to no avail... **What'd I miss?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `I18n.l` method as follows:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > I18n.l Time.now.to_date, :format => :long_dateweek
 => "Wednesday, August 22, 2012" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > I18n.l Time.now, :format => :very_short
 => "23:03"
```

You can also use the `l` helper method in your views. Look at this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) for more information.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! A bit more "cumbersome" than I was expecting...but simple enough...

Comment: After further inspection the methods, `I18n.l`, that you provide appear to return the time in UTC format instead of the local *PDT* that the application is config'd for. Any idea how to get the response in the local zone? tried `I18n.l Time.now.to_time(:local), :format => :very_short`, among other things, to no avail...

Comment: It looks to me like using `Time.now` uses the local timezone of the server which the app is running on. If you want to use the timezone which you set in the config file, you need to use `Time.zone.now` instead.

Answer (score 3):

@alexsanford1 has the right answer. I modified mine below to work in the view.

```
<%= l Time.now, :format => :very_short %>
```

Comment: that gets me `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`. And `Time.now.to_time.to_s(:format => :very_short)` gets me the same default format as before: `"2012-08-22 18:49:22 -0700"`