# Why doesn't rails honor my date formats in en.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to have a custom format, `:results` so I can do a `@obj.date.to_s(:results)` call in my views.

If I put my custom format in an initializer then it works:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:results] = "%D"
```

However if I try and put that in my `en.yml` file then it does not work (as in it will not format it as expected):

```
en:
  time:
    # See also config/initializers/time_formats.rb for lambda based configs
    formats:
      results: '%D'
  date:
    formats:
      default: '%m/%d/%Y"'
      results: '%D'
```

Everything I read suggests that this should work.  What am I missing?

**EDIT:** This is basically a duplicate of [Rails not picking up custom date & time formats in en.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082665/rails-not-picking-up-custom-date-time-formats-in-en-yml?rq=1) So I guess the question is how can I set the defaults in yml rather than an initialize (it is easier to manage).  Is there a built in way, or do I need to manually load the yaml file and set the `Time::DATE_FORMAT` hash myself?

Comment: What do you get when you use that format?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in [Rails not picking up custom date & time formats in en.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082665/rails-not-picking-up-custom-date-time-formats-in-en-yml?rq=1)

The second way you mentioned is using I18n (internationalization) which means to use it you hace to call it.

In your views you can do

```
<%= l @obj.date, format: :result %>
```